# Are PostgreSQL tables automatically re-indexed after an update?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, reindex

If I index a PostgreSQL table and then update it, do I need to re-index the table or is it automatically re-indexed?

Can someone provide a link to PostgreSQL documentation for further reading? I've got this so far:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> indexes in PostgreSQL do not need maintenance or tuning

You do not need to re-index manually.

For more details, please also read 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html

Answer (score 2):

From further reading in the PostgreSQL documentation:

> Once an index is created, no further intervention is required: the
>   system will update the index when the table is modified, and it will
>   use the index in queries when it thinks doing so would be more
>   efficient than a sequential table scan. But you might have to run the
>   ANALYZE command regularly to update statistics to allow the query
>   planner to make educated decisions. See Chapter 14 for information
>   about how to find out whether an index is used and when and why the
>   planner might choose not to use an index.

See:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-intro.html